# Why does a class that implements ArrayAccess, Iterator, and Countable not work with array_filter()?

Tags: php, custom-controls, array-filter

I have the following class:

```
<?php

/*
* Abstract class that, when subclassed, allows an instance to be used as an array.
* Interfaces `Countable` and `Iterator` are necessary for functionality such as `foreach`
*/
abstract class AArray implements ArrayAccess, Iterator, Countable
{
    private $container = array();

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) 
    {
        if (is_null($offset)) {
            $this->container[] = $value;
        } else {
            $this->container[$offset] = $value;
        }
    }

    public function offsetExists($offset) 
    {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset) 
    {
        unset($this->container[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset) 
    {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]) ? $this->container[$offset] : null;
    }

    public function rewind() {
            reset($this->container);
    }

    public function current() {
            return current($this->container);
    }

    public function key() {
            return key($this->container);
    }

    public function next() {
            return next($this->container);
    }

    public function valid() {
            return $this->current() !== false;
    }   

    public function count() {
     return count($this->container);
    }

}

?>
```

Then, I have another class that sub-classes AArray:

```
<?php

require_once 'AArray.inc';

class GalleryCollection extends AArray { }

?>
```

When I fill a GalleryCollection instance with data and then try to use it in `array_filter()`, in the first argument, I get the following error:

```
Warning: array_filter() [function.array-filter]: The first argument should be an array in
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `array_filter` only works with arrays.

Look at other options, like [`FilterIterator`](http://php.net/FilterIterator), or create an array from your object first.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to extend the Array class and use an instance of that extension in `array_filter()`?

Comment: It's not possible and `array` is not a class (php 5.3).

Comment: @letseatfood, `array_filter` will only work on things that are of the `array` type in PHP… not `object` as any class instances will be. If you want to get an array out of an iterator, use [`iterator_to_array()`](http://php.net/iterator_to_array).  To filter the values in the iterator, as Artefacto said, you should be using a `FilterIterator`.

Comment: Thank-you. I wasn't sure if it was an array or not.

Comment: @VolkerK - Ugh I feel silly. @salathe - Thanks VERY MUCH for sharing the `iterator_to_array()` function. With @Artefacto's suggestion to create an array from the object, I was able to do it easily with `iterator_to_array()`.